# Google web app to log page accesses to Google docs, slides, sheets, etc

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a range of Google docs that are publicly viewable, but I would like to get some information about how often they are being viewed. I understand that there used to be a way of doing this with Google Analytics, but now that has been removed.

It seems to me that I have two main options, one of which is to make all my doc links point to a page which redirects according to a query string parameter, e.g.:

```
http://myurl.net?page=1         # Sends you to one page and logs the visit
http://myurl.net?page=2         # Sends you to another page and logs the visit
```

Or alternatively, I could try to embed some code in each doc that makes a call back to the server with its page number. But I don't know if this is possible.

The first option looks like it should be fairly easy, but I don't see how to redirect the client.

Could anyone give me some ideas about how to do this? It seems it would be useful for quite a lot of people.

Many thanks.

Justin.

Comment: There is still no way in Google drive to get some information about how often your docs are being viewed. You can use a [Google's URL shortener](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) service at  [goo.gl](https://goo.gl/)  which allows tracking who clicked the url.

Comment: That's useful abielita. Thank you.